# Slider should return to zero

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, animation

I want to have a slider that returns to 0 when the user stops dragging.

So far I have this:

```
<Window x:Class="CenteredSliderTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel>
    <!--Value="{Binding ZSpeed}"-->
    <Slider DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                x:Name="ZSlider"
                                Minimum="-100" Maximum="100"
                                SelectionStart="-20" SelectionEnd="20"
                                Orientation="Vertical" 
                                TickFrequency="10" 
                                TickPlacement="TopLeft" 
                                AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft"
                                AutoToolTipPrecision="2"
                                LargeChange="10"
                                SmallChange="1"
                                IsDirectionReversed="True"
                                Focusable="False"
                                >
        <Slider.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostMouseCapture" SourceName="ZSlider">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ZSlider"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
                                From="{Binding Value, ElementName=ZSlider}"
                                To="0.0"
                                Duration="0:0:1.5"
                                FillBehavior="Stop"
                                />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>

            </EventTrigger>
        </Slider.Triggers>
    </Slider>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ZSpeed}" />
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

This works as long as I don't bind the slider value to my DependencyProperty ZSpeed.

As soon as I do this, the slider jumps back to the original value and at the second attempt the slider can't be dragged anymore.

So what can I do (preferable in xaml) in order to get the animation modify not only the slider but also the ZSpeed property?

**EDIT**

Code in MainWindow:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public double ZSpeed
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ZSpeedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ZSpeedProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ZSpeed.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ZSpeedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ZSpeed", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));



    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        Binding binding = new Binding("Value") { Source = ZSlider }; 
        this.SetBinding(ZSpeedProperty, binding); 
    }

}
```

Comment: does specifying `OneWay` on the binding help at all?

Comment: Yes, but then ZSpeed isn't set accordingly.

Comment: Why don't you bind your anymation to `ZSpeed`? The slider will be updated automatically. Disclaimer: I never worked with animations, so I don't know if this is going to work.

Comment: I tried Storyboard.TargetProperty="DataContext.ZSpeed", but after the animation the slider always jumps back to the last drag position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might reverse the direction of the binding. Instead of binding the Slider's `Value` to `ZSpeed` you could bind `ZSpeed` to `Value`. This would also be the "natural" binding direction if the Slider is meant to change `ZSpeed`, but `ZSpeed` won't change otherwise.

EDIT: If `ZSpeed` is a dependency property in some data class `MyData` you could create a binding in code like this:

```
MyData dataObject = ...
Binding binding = new Binding("Value") { Source = ZSlider };
dataObject.SetBinding(MyData.ZSpeedProperty, binding);
```

**SECOND EDIT:** Picking up Daniels suggestion, you might animate `ZSpeed` instead of the Slider's `Value`. Bind the `Value` to `ZSpeed` as before, remove the EventTrigger and add an event handler for `LostMouseCapture`:

```
<Slider x:Name="ZSlider" ...
        Value="{Binding ZSpeed}"
        LostMouseCapture="ZSlider_LostMouseCapture"/>
```

Code behind:

```
private void ZSlider_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = ZSpeed,
        To = 0d,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5 * Math.Abs(ZSpeed) / 100d),
        FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
    };
    ZSpeed = 0d;
    BeginAnimation(ZSpeedProperty, animation);
}
```

Comment: ZSpeed is a DependencyProperty of my view model, how can I do this? I don't know how to "reverse the direction of binding". And by the way ZSpeed can change otherwise.

Comment: After doing this: Binding binding = new Binding("Value") { Source = ZSlider }; this.SetBinding(ZSpeedProperty, binding);
ZSpeed is animated to 0 and then jumps back to the original value. The Slider doesn't move while animation runs.

Comment: I did exactly that (i.e. have ZSpeed in MainWindow) and it works for me. Did you forget to remove `Value="{Binding ZSpeed}"` from the Slider?

Comment: And you might get tricked by the fact that the animation gets started on every `LostMouseCapture`, even if the slider is still in the center. Then it runs for 1.5 seconds from 0 to 0 and you can't intercept it. The duration should perhaps be proportional to the displacement from the center.

Comment: Yes I removed Value="{Binding ZSpeed}". While I drag the slider, ZSpeed is updated correctly. But when I release the slider, the slider stays on this last position and the animation runs on ZSpeed only. After the animation ZSpeed jumps from 0 to the value of the slider.

Comment: How is your ZSpeedProperty defined? Does it perhaps bind two-way by default? I think it should bind one-way, but than changes in ZSpeed won't be reflected by the Slider. It's the same problem as before.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is working. So it seems that the only way to achieve this behavior is by doing it in code behind. Unfortunatly no way to do this in pure xaml.

Comment: Or at least none we could figure out :-)

Answer (score 1):

<s>You should be using `FillBehavior.HoldEnd`.</s>

Edit: That apparently doesn't work. You could set the `ZSpeed` value to 0 manually in the `StoryBoard.Completed` event.

Comment: HoldEnd freezes the slider after the animation.